# CSS :hover pseudo-class is not working in my code

Tags: html, css

I used hover pseudo-class to change color on anchor element `<a>` but its result is not like that I want. It is not working . Help me please. Thank you very much.
JSFiddle here -     http://jsfiddle.net/km9287u3/6/

Comment: Please help us to help you as easy a you can by not going off site to find relevant code. Preferably provide a [mcve] here. Also please be more descriptive than "it's result is unexpected". What is actually expected.

Comment: This is my first question relate to HTML CSS. I don't know How to attach link to my code. Sorry. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Change `a:hover` to `#nav a:hover` It will work.

Comment: Use the button that looks like `<>` in the editor to add an interactive snippet, or  ctrl + m.

Answer (score 2):

You have a [specificty](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue. `div#nav a` is more sepcific than `a:hover`. Make your hover rule more specific, as below.

```css
div#nav a {
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div#nav a:hover {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">

  </div>
  <div id="nav" class="navigation">
    <a id="home" href="Ajax_Load_Content_to_Page.html">HOME</a>
    <a id="route" href="Ajax2.html">ROUTE</a>
    <a id="toys" href="Ajax3.html">TOYS</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Just a few seconds faster :D